# Setting up direct Ethernet connection

Tags: linux, windows, networking

I have two desktop systems, one with Windows 10 and the other one using Debian 9. All my data are stored on the linux system, whose is mounted as a network drive under Windows using Samba.

I want to setup a direct ethernet connection between the two computer using a dedicated gigabit ethernet network card, to avoid saturating the network. So I configured both computers to use static IP addressing:

*/etc/network/interfaces:*

```
auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet static
    address 192.168.253.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 192.168.253.0
    broadcast 192.168.253.255
```

*Windows adapter:*
[image: Windows configuration screenshot]

But both hosts can't ping each others. I also have these issues in the log of the Linux computer:

```
NetworkManager[466]: <info>  [1544785487.5682] device (enp6s0): Activation: starting connection 'enp6s0' (0169b53d-570d-477c-b45a-5edd8f1e57a3)
NetworkManager[466]: <info>  [1544785487.5685] device (enp6s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
NetworkManager[466]: <info>  [1544785487.5687] device (enp6s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
NetworkManager[466]: <info>  [1544785487.5688] device (enp6s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
NetworkManager[466]: <warn>  [1544785487.5688] device (enp6s0): interface enp6s0 not up for IP configuration
avahi-daemon[462]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp6s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.253.1.
avahi-daemon[462]: New relevant interface enp6s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
avahi-daemon[462]: Registering new address record for 192.168.253.1 on enp6s0.IPv4.
kernel: [ 4090.228869] r8169 0000:06:00.0 enp6s0: link down
kernel: [ 4090.228917] r8169 0000:06:00.0 enp6s0: link down
kernel: [ 4090.228943] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp6s0: link is not ready
NetworkManager[466]: <info>  [1544785487.7322] device (enp6s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
NetworkManager[466]: <info>  [1544785487.7328] device (enp6s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
NetworkManager[466]: <info>  [1544785487.7330] device (enp6s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
NetworkManager[466]: <info>  [1544785487.7387] device (enp6s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

So what could be missing in my configuration ?

Comment: If the network interfaces don't support autosensing you need a crossover cable or a hub/switch inbetween.

Comment: Well, I suppose that any network card bought in 2018 should support that.

Comment: It should, yes, but I would not bet on it. And the `link down` messages do point that way.

Comment: If your netmask is `255.255.0.0`, your network should be `192.168.0.0` and your broadcast would be `192.168.255.255` - if this is not the intention, move to a smaller network - netmask:`255.255.255.0` network:`192.168.253.0` broadcast:`192.168.253.255`

Comment: Your Linux network is incorrect. It's listed as 192.168.253.0. With a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0 it should be 192.168.0.0. I don't know anything about Linux so I don't know why that would be like that, but try changing the subnet mask on both devices to 255.255.255.0.

Comment: First, the /network/interfaces address is incorrect (192.168.253.1 is netmask 255.255.255.0). Then I would recommend to use a MUCH [smaller network](https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html), like /30. Also your log is pointing to MDI/X errors, so setting one of both sides static will most likely help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure Automatic MDI/MDI-X is enabled:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/2qivsa/how_to_determine_if_nic_is_auto_mdimdix_capable/cn6i19t
There shouldn't be any more configuration.
You can make sure by temporally connecting both computers to a switch.

Answer (score 0):

Finally one of the network card was misfunctionning. Replacing the card and setting up the correct network mask solved the issue.